# PHP how to execute a script with SOAP requests closing browser windows

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I developed a PHP script that makes some calls to a SOAP web service.
When I get results I modify data and append them in a CSV file.

I have a MySQL table FOUNDS that contains all my founds ID that use to query the web service

```
FOUNDS
| ID   | status  |
| AADR | ok      |
| AAIT | ok      |
| AAXJ | pending |
| ACIM | pending |
```

I wrote a PHP page that reads from FOUNDS table with a 10 rows LIMIT and query on soap service, get the results, write them into the CSV, and flag the row as "ok".

After looping on retrieved rows the script check if I have other "pending" rows.

If the total number of "pending" rows is greater than zero I do a PHP location to itself. Basically the page reloads itself. Otherwise it makes a PHP location to an other page.

When we started I had only 100 ID's in FOUNDS tables.

Now I have 40.000 rows in the FOUNDS table and the process takes like 8/10 hours to complete.

How can I modify my script in a way that I don't need to keep my browser open and without a timeout?

Comment: Please read through your question and correct the grammar/spelling. I'm not sure what you're asking. What I do know is that we can't help you if we don't know what code you have. Please include the essential parts of your script in the question.

Comment: i modify my question i hope that now is more clear

Comment: Formatting and grammar